# Image upload on rails 4 using paperclip shows broken image

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip, broken-image

Before I begin, I would like to say that I have googled and tried multiple solutions that were offered. I am still encountering the same issue.

When I upload an image using paperclip, it displays a broken image. I right clicked and inspected and found that my page is raising and error : Get http://localhost:3000/system/pins/images/000/000/008/medium/imgres.jpg 404 (Not Found).

View

```
<%= image_tag @pin.image.url %>
<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @pin.description %>
</p>

<% if @pin.user == current_user %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(@pin) %> 
<%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
<% end %>
```

Model

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb =>         "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

Controller

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if     @pin.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white     list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.6'


gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'

gem 'bootstrap-sass'

gem 'devise'

gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.0'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3' 
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

I've tried downgrading and upgrading my gem file, adding a cocaine gem, adding :path => "" and :url => "" to my model, setting the timestamp to false, restarting my computer and my server, uninstalling and reinstalling imagemagick, downloading the file.exe manually and adjusting the code to in development.rb as instructed, and changing the location of my image. I may be forgetting some things I've tried, because I've been searching on google and adjusting for hours now. Is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1):

At a high level paperclip writes the uploaded file to a local file and stores information on the file in the database for lookup. The fact that rails is returning a 404 indicates that either 1) the file isn't being written or 2) rails isn't serving the file correctly.

The paperclip documentation on storage is pretty good as a reference: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage

By default rails should serve files that are in the public directory and by default paperclip stores files under `public/system`, so generally file serving should work in the development environment automatically.

Can you verify that the file `public/system/pins/images/000/000/008/medium/imgres.jpg` exists?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Is there a command I can run through gitbush to check? When I look in the file on sublime text it does exist.

Comment: Also, the file is under original/imgres.jpg. I removed the :medium parameter from my erb.